# Combine functions to reduce queries

Tags: python, function

From [Python Problem Set](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ProblemSets/99%20Prolog%20Problems%20Solutions) The three functions work correctly but they require executing one at a time before moving to the next in order to get the final result. Is there a way to obtain the result from all three without having to query each one individually?

```
>>> import itertools

>>> def prime_factors(value):
    if value > 3:
        for this in itertools.chain(iter([2]), xrange(3,int(value ** 0.5)+1, 2)):
            if this*this > value:  break
            while not (value % this):
                if value == this: break
                value /=  this
                yield this
    yield value

>>> prime_factors(315)
generator object prime_factors at 0x01182468>

>>> def prime_factors_mult(n):
    res = list(prime_factors(n))
    return sorted([fact, res.count(fact)] for fact in set(res))

>>> prime_factors_mult(315)
[[3, 2], [5, 1], [7, 1]]

>>> def totient(n):
    from operator import mul
    if n == 1: return 1
    return reduce(mul, [(p-1) * p**(m-1) for p,m in prime_factors_mult(n)])

>>> totient(315)
144
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "obtain the result from all three without having to query each one individually". Do you mean calling all three in sequence? If so, you can create a function that calls the three of them, and returns an array (for instance), with the results. Did I miss the point?

Comment: Wait, is this the Euler totient (phi) function?

Comment: First thing I'd do would be caching a list of prime numbers, extending it if larger primes are needed. This would speed up calls to `prime_factors` significantly, and probably would speed things up if you need only _one_ `totient` value.

Comment: @pcalcao That might work, have an example?

Comment: @Blender Yep, added a link to the reference, could be similar to [totient_function](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ProblemSets/99%20Prolog%20Problems%20Solutions#Problem_34:_Calculate_Euclid.27s_totient_function)

Comment: @9000 Caching the list how? Through an array?

Comment: @Astron: yes, caching prime numbers in a Python list (word 'array' is rarely used). Add a function `find_primes(maximum)` and use `find_primes(value**0.5)` in `prime_factors`. The `find_primes` will consult a global list of primes; if list's last value is less than `maximum`, it will generate enough primes using Eratosthenes method and append them to the primes list. Initially the list of primes would be just [2], though you could supply more :) The lookup will speed up subsequent calculation of `totient`.

Comment: @9000 Thanks for the awesome input, hopefully I can use that in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the second 2, but the generator should stay a generator:

```
In [1]: import itertools
In [2]: from operator import mul

In [3]: def prime_factors(value):
            if value > 3:
                for this in itertools.chain(iter([2]), xrange(3,int(value ** 0.5) + 1, 2)):
                    if (this * this) > value:
                        break
                    while not (value % this):
                        if value == this:
                            break
                        value /= this
                        yield this
            yield value

In [4]: def totient(n):
            if n != 1:
                res = list(prime_factors(n))
                prime_factors_mult = sorted([fact, res.count(fact)] for fact in set(res))
                retValue = reduce(mul, [(p-1) * p**(m-1) for p,m in prime_factors_mult]), prime_factors_mult
            else:
                retValue = n
            return retValue

In [5]: x = totient(315)

In [6]: print x
(144, [[3, 2], [5, 1], [7, 1]])

In [7]: print x[0]
144

In [8]: print x[1]
[[3, 2], [5, 1], [7, 1]]
```

---

You actually can combine all 3 and have the 1 function return a 3-tuple of what each ones return value would be:

```
import itertools
from operator import mul

def totient(n):
    if n == 1:  return 1
    res = list()
    value = int("%d" % n)
    if value > 3:
        for this in itertools.chain(iter([2]), xrange(3,int(value ** 0.5)+1, 2)):
            if this*this > value:  break
            while not (value % this):
                if value == this:  break
                value /= this
                res.append(this)
    res.append(value)
    prime_factors_mult = sorted([fact, res.count(fact)] for fact in set(res))
    return res, reduce(mul, [(p - 1) * p**(m - 1) for p,m in prime_factors_mult]), prime_factors_mult

x = totient(315)

# This would be the returned list from prime_factors(315)
print x[0]
[3, 3, 5, 7]

# This would be the returned value from totient(315)
print x[1]
144

# This would be the returned list from prime_factors_mult(315)
print x[2]
[[3, 2], [5, 1], [7, 1]]

# The 3-tuple:
print x
([3, 3, 5, 7], 144, [[3, 2], [5, 1], [7, 1]])
```

Comment: Can the prime factors still be returned from the original `prime_factors_mult` in the totient function?

Comment: @Astron check my edits, I made it into 1 single function that returns a 3-tuple of what each function alone would have returned `([3, 3, 5, 7], 144, [[3, 2], [5, 1], [7, 1]])`.